# What is the most elegant way to remove a path from the $PATH variable in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, path, variable-expansion, list-processing

Or more generally, how do I remove an item from a colon-separated list in a Bash environment variable?

I thought I had seen a simple way to do this years ago, using the more advanced forms of Bash variable expansion, but if so I've lost track of it.  A quick search of Google turned up surprisingly few relevant results and none that I would call "simple" or "elegant".  For example, two methods using sed and awk, respectively:

```
PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed -e 's;:\?/home/user/bin;;' -e 's;/home/user/bin:\?;;')
PATH=!(awk -F: '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(!($i in a)){a[$i];printf s$i;s=":"}}}'<<<$PATH)
```

Does nothing straightforward exist?  Is there anything analogous to a split() function in Bash?

**Update:**
It looks like I need to apologize for my intentionally-vague question; I was less interested in solving a specific use-case than in provoking good discussion.  Fortunately, I got it!

There are some very clever techniques here.  In the end, I've added the following three functions to my toolbox.  The magic happens in path_remove, which is based largely on Martin York's clever use of `awk`'s RS variable.

```
path_append ()  { path_remove $1; export PATH="$PATH:$1"; }
path_prepend () { path_remove $1; export PATH="$1:$PATH"; }
path_remove ()  { export PATH=`echo -n $PATH | awk -v RS=: -v ORS=: '$0 != "'$1'"' | sed 's/:$//'`; }
```

The only real cruft in there is the use of `sed` to remove the trailing colon.  Considering how straightforward the rest of Martin's solution is, though, I'm quite willing to live with it!

---

Related question: [[How do I manipulate $PATH elements in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273909/how-do-i-manipulate-path-elements-in-shell-scripts)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273909/how-do-i-manipulate-path-elements-in-shell-scripts)

Comment: For any variable: `WORK=\`echo -n ${1} | awk -v RS=: -v ORS=: '$0 != "'${3}'"' | sed 's/:$//'\`; eval "export ${2}=${WORK}"` but you must call it as `func $VAR VAR pattern` (based on @martin-york and @andrew-aylett)

Comment: I stumbled on this question whilst looking for a way to update `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` etc., however, after a couple of happy hours bash  scripting, it struck me, that we might all be better off using [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A minute with awk:

```
# Strip all paths with SDE in them.
#
export PATH=`echo ${PATH} | awk -v RS=: -v ORS=: '/SDE/ {next} {print}'`
```

#### Edit: It response to comments below:

```
$ export a="/a/b/c/d/e:/a/b/c/d/g/k/i:/a/b/c/d/f:/a/b/c/g:/a/b/c/d/g/i"
$ echo ${a}
/a/b/c/d/e:/a/b/c/d/f:/a/b/c/g:/a/b/c/d/g/i

## Remove multiple (any directory with a: all of them)
$ echo ${a} | awk -v RS=: -v ORS=: '/a/ {next} {print}'
## Works fine all removed

## Remove multiple including last two: (any directory with g)
$ echo ${a} | awk -v RS=: -v ORS=: '/g/ {next} {print}'
/a/b/c/d/e:/a/b/c/d/f:
## Works fine: Again!
```

#### Edit in response to security problem: (that is not relevant to the question)

```
export PATH=$(echo ${PATH} | awk -v RS=: -v ORS=: '/SDE/ {next} {print}' | sed 's/:*$//')
```

This removes any trailing colons left by deleting the last entries, which would effectively add `.` to your path.

Comment: Fails when trying to remove the last element or multiple elements: in the first case, it adds the current dir (as the empty string; a potential security hole), in the second case it adds ` ` as a path element.

Comment: @larsmans: Works fine for me. Note: Empty is not the same as current directory which is "./"

Comment: An empty string as a "member" of the `PATH` variable *does*, as a special rule, denote current directory in all Unix shells since at least V7 Unix of 1979. It still does in `bash`. Check the manual or try for yourself.

Comment: @Martin: POSIX does not require this behavior, but does document and allow it: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Comment: @larsmans: Interesting. Easily fixed though. Though anybody that had any concerns about security in relation to this question could have easily asked it as a separate question rather then muddy the waters of this question with irrelevant points. In the end I still prefer my alternative answer of using vi to do the job.

Comment: There's an even more subtle issue when removing the last element with this: [awk seems to add a null byte to the end of the string](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/67). Meaning that if you append another directory to PATH later, it will in fact not be searched.

Comment: Can you explain the `awk` functionality?

Comment: @Jacktose `RS` => Record separator. So split the line by ':' to apply the rules against. `ORS` => Output record separator. So when we put it back togther seporate the records by ':' again. Rule 1: `/SDE/ {next}` If the record contains "/SDE/" then ignore the record and move to the next record. Rule 2: `{print}` Any record that did not match rule 1 will match rule 2 and is simply printed. The result is removing any paths with "/SDE/" in them from the PATH environment variable. Not perfect as noted in comments but will cover the majority of cases.

Comment: @sschuberth I don't see the null byte with `awk -v RS=: -v ORS=: '{ print }' <<<"${PATH}" | xxd`. When I add the `sed` to trim the trailing `:`, I do see a null byte, but I think that's just the string terminator; when I then append to the path with `PATH="${PATH}:foo"`, the resulting `$PATH` still only has one `0a`, at the very end (following, not preceeding `:foo`).

Answer (score 66):

My dirty hack:

```
echo ${PATH} > t1
vi t1
export PATH=$(cat t1)
```

Comment: It's never a good sign when the most obvious solution is to *de*-automate the process.  :-D

Comment: SO much safer than the "elegant" alternatives.

Comment: How did something as useless as this get so many upvotes?

Answer (score 52):

Since the big issue with substitution is the end cases, how about making the end cases no different to the other cases?  If the path already had colons at the start and end, we could simply search for our desired string wrapped with colons.  As it is, we can easily add those colons and remove them afterwards.

```
# PATH => /bin:/opt/a dir/bin:/sbin
WORK=:$PATH:
# WORK => :/bin:/opt/a dir/bin:/sbin:
REMOVE='/opt/a dir/bin'
WORK=${WORK/:$REMOVE:/:}
# WORK => :/bin:/sbin:
WORK=${WORK%:}
WORK=${WORK#:}
PATH=$WORK
# PATH => /bin:/sbin
```

Pure bash :).

Comment: I'd add this tutorial section for some extra frosting: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: I used this because it looked like the simplest solution. It was super fast and easy, and you can easily check your work with echo $WORK right before the last line where you actually change the PATH variable.

Comment: Absolutely a little gem. Exactly what I was trying to do when I found this post. -Thank you Andrew! BTW: Maybe you'd like to add double-quotes around ":$PATH:", just in case it should contain spaces (same about "/usr/bin") and last line "$WORK".

Comment: Thanks, @PacMan-- :).  I'm pretty sure (just tried it) you don't need spaces for the assignments to `WORK` and `PATH` as the variable expansion happens after the line is parsed into sections for variable assignment and command execution.  `REMOVE` might need to be quoted, or you could just put your string straight into the replacement if it's a constant.

Comment: I always got confused over when strings were preserved, thus I started always to double-quote strings. Thanks again for clarifying this. :)

Answer (score 27):

Here's the simplest solution i can devise:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=:
# convert it to an array
t=($PATH)
unset IFS
# perform any array operations to remove elements from the array
t=(${t[@]%%*usr*})
IFS=:
# output the new array
echo "${t[*]}"
```

The above example will remove any element in $PATH that contains "usr". You can replace "*usr*" with "/home/user/bin" to remove just that element.

**update** per [sschuberth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1127485/sschuberth)

Even though i think spaces in a `$PATH` are a **horrible** idea, here's a solution that handles it:

```
PATH=$(IFS=':';t=($PATH);n=${#t[*]};a=();for ((i=0;i<n;i++)); do p="${t[i]%%*usr*}"; [ "${p}" ] && a[i]="${p}"; done;echo "${a[*]}");
```

or

```
IFS=':'
t=($PATH)
n=${#t[*]}
a=()
for ((i=0;i<n;i++)); do
  p="${t[i]%%*usr*}"
  [ "${p}" ] && a[i]="${p}"
done
echo "${a[*]}"
```

Comment: As one liner:
PATH=$(IFS=':';t=($PATH);unset IFS;t=(${t[@]%%*usr*});IFS=':';echo "${t[*]}");

Comment: This solution does not work with paths in PATH that contain spaces; it replaces them by colons.

Comment: Will replace partial matches. Will incorrectly filter names with pattern metacharacters.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a one-liner that, despite the current [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/370192/1127485) and [highest rated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/370255/1127485) answers, does not add invisible characters to PATH and can cope with paths that contain spaces:

```
export PATH=$(p=$(echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | grep -v "/cygwin/" | tr "\n" ":"); echo ${p%:})
```

Personally, I also find this easy to read / understand, and it only involves common commands instead of using awk.

Comment: ... and if you want something that can cope even with newlines in filenames, you could use this:  

`export PATH=$(p=$(echo $PATH | tr ":" "\0" | grep -v -z "/cygwin/" | tr "\0" ":"); echo ${p%:})`  

(though arguably, you might want to ask yourself why you need this, if you do :))

Comment: This will remove partial matches, which is probably not what you want; I would use `grep -v "^/path/to/remove\$"` or `grep -v -x "/path/to/remove"`

Comment: Fine solution, but do you really think `tr` is more common than `awk`? ;)

Comment: Absolutely. Light-weight environments, like Git Bash on Windows, rather come with a simple tool like `tr` rather than an interpreter like `awk`.

Comment: @ehdr: You need to replace `echo "..."` with `printf "%s" "..."` for it to work on paths like `-e` and similar. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49418406/102441

Comment: Personally I preffer a single awk to a string of pipes. awk is great and perfectly "common". Even better are the less-readable answers that don't use any pipes orr externals at all. THAT is the way to do it. If you're going to try to critique the other answers, you open the door for observations about the weakness of your own.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a  solution that:

- is pure Bash,
- does not invoke other processes (like 'sed' or 'awk'),
- does not change `IFS`,
- does not fork a sub-shell,
- handles paths with spaces, and
- removes all occurrences of the argument in `PATH`.

  ```
  removeFromPath() {
     local p d
     p=":$1:"
     d=":$PATH:"
     d=${d//$p/:}
     d=${d/#:/}
     PATH=${d/%:/}
  }
  ```

Comment: I like this solution. Maybe make the variable names more descriptive?

Comment: very nice. However, does not work for path segments containing an asterisk (*). Sometimes they get there accidentally.

Comment: Best / simplest answer IMO. Slightly shorter (not that it was too long however ;-) ): `rmpath() { local d; d=:$PATH:; d=${d//:$1:/:}; d=${d#:}; PATH=${d%:}; }`

Comment: Cannot delete two identical entries that come one after another.

Comment: this solution is the best.

Answer (score 7):

The best pure bash option I have found so far is the following:

```
function path_remove {
  # Delete path by parts so we can never accidentally remove sub paths
  PATH=${PATH//":$1:"/":"} # delete any instances in the middle
  PATH=${PATH/#"$1:"/} # delete any instance at the beginning
  PATH=${PATH/%":$1"/} # delete any instance at the end
}
```

This is based on the [not quite correct answer](https://superuser.com/a/462852/16858) to [Add directory to $PATH if it's not already there](https://superuser.com/q/39751/16858) over on Superuser, fixing issues mentioned in comments.

Obviously this can be made into a single line function if you don't want the explanatory comments.

Comment: This is quite good too. I tested it. If there is a duplicate path (eg. two that are exactly the same) in PATH, then only one of them is removed. You can also make it into a one-liner: `removePath () { PATH=${PATH/":$1"/}; PATH=${PATH/"$1:"/}; }`

Comment: This solution fails when the `$PATH` contains a sub-folder of the target (i.e. to be deleted) path.   For example: `a:abc/def/bin:b` -> `a/bin:b`, when `abc/def` is to be deleted.

Answer (score 6):

I've just been using the functions in the bash distribution, that have been there apparently since 1991.  These are still in the bash-docs package on Fedora, and used to be used in `/etc/profile`, but no more...

```
$ rpm -ql bash-doc |grep pathfunc
/usr/share/doc/bash-4.2.20/examples/functions/pathfuncs
$ cat $(!!)
cat $(rpm -ql bash-doc |grep pathfunc)
#From: "Simon J. Gerraty" <sjg@zen.void.oz.au>
#Message-Id: <199510091130.VAA01188@zen.void.oz.au>
#Subject: Re: a shell idea?
#Date: Mon, 09 Oct 1995 21:30:20 +1000


# NAME:
#       add_path.sh - add dir to path
#
# DESCRIPTION:
#       These functions originated in /etc/profile and ksh.kshrc, but
#       are more useful in a separate file.
#
# SEE ALSO:
#       /etc/profile
#
# AUTHOR:
#       Simon J. Gerraty <sjg@zen.void.oz.au>

#       @(#)Copyright (c) 1991 Simon J. Gerraty
#
#       This file is provided in the hope that it will
#       be of use.  There is absolutely NO WARRANTY.
#       Permission to copy, redistribute or otherwise
#       use this file is hereby granted provided that
#       the above copyright notice and this notice are
#       left intact.

# is $1 missing from $2 (or PATH) ?
no_path() {
        eval "case :\$${2-PATH}: in *:$1:*) return 1;; *) return 0;; esac"
}
# if $1 exists and is not in path, append it
add_path () {
  [ -d ${1:-.} ] && no_path $* && eval ${2:-PATH}="\$${2:-PATH}:$1"
}
# if $1 exists and is not in path, prepend it
pre_path () {
  [ -d ${1:-.} ] && no_path $* && eval ${2:-PATH}="$1:\$${2:-PATH}"
}
# if $1 is in path, remove it
del_path () {
  no_path $* || eval ${2:-PATH}=`eval echo :'$'${2:-PATH}: |
    sed -e "s;:$1:;:;g" -e "s;^:;;" -e "s;:\$;;"`
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
function __path_remove(){  
    local D=":${PATH}:";  
    [ "${D/:$1:/:}" != "$D" ] && PATH="${D/:$1:/:}";  
    PATH="${PATH/#:/}";  
    export PATH="${PATH/%:/}";  
}
```

Dug it out from my .bashrc file.
When you play around with PATH, and it gets lost, awk/sed/grep becomes unavailable :-)

Comment: That's a very good point. (I never was fond of executing external utilities for simple things like this).

Answer (score 5):

Linux from Scratch defines three Bash functions in `/etc/profile`:

```
# Functions to help us manage paths.  Second argument is the name of the
# path variable to be modified (default: PATH)
pathremove () {
        local IFS=':'
        local NEWPATH
        local DIR
        local PATHVARIABLE=${2:-PATH}
        for DIR in ${!PATHVARIABLE} ; do
                if [ "$DIR" != "$1" ] ; then
                  NEWPATH=${NEWPATH:+$NEWPATH:}$DIR
                fi
        done
        export $PATHVARIABLE="$NEWPATH"
}

pathprepend () {
        pathremove $1 $2
        local PATHVARIABLE=${2:-PATH}
        export $PATHVARIABLE="$1${!PATHVARIABLE:+:${!PATHVARIABLE}}"
}

pathappend () {
        pathremove $1 $2
        local PATHVARIABLE=${2:-PATH}
        export $PATHVARIABLE="${!PATHVARIABLE:+${!PATHVARIABLE}:}$1"
}

export -f pathremove pathprepend pathappend
```

Ref: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/profile.html

Answer (score 3):

Well, in bash, as it supports regular expression, I would simply do :

```
PATH=${PATH/:\/home\/user\/bin/}
```

Comment: Isn't it only pathname expansion, not regular expressions?

Comment: While bash does support regular expressions (as of bash 3), this is not an example of it, this is a variable substitution.

Comment: This is pattern variable expantion and the solution has several problems. 1) it will not match the first element. 2) it will match anything that starts with "/home/user/bin", not just "/home/user/bin". 3) it requires escaping special characters. At best, i'd say this is an incomplete example.

Answer (score 3):

I did write an answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273909/how-do-i-manipulate-path-elements-in-shell-scripts#346860) (using awk too). But i'm not sure that's what you are looking for? It at least looks clear to me what it does, instead of trying to fit into one line. For a simple one liner, though, that only removes stuff, i recommend

```
echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | awk '$0 != "/bin"' | paste -sd:
```

Replacing is

```
echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | 
    awk '$0 != "/bin"; $0 == "/bin" { print "/bar" }' | paste -sd:
```

or (shorter but less readable)

```
echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | awk '$0 == "/bin" { print "/bar"; next } 1' | paste -sd:
```

Anyway, for the same question, and a whole lot of useful answers, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273909/how-do-i-manipulate-path-elements-in-shell-scripts).

Comment: And if you want to remove a lines which contains a partial string use `awk '$0 !~ "/bin"'`. I.e. keep lines that do not contain '/bin' with the awk operator `!~`.

Answer (score 3):

> ## What is the most elegant way to remove a path from the $PATH variable in Bash?

What's more elegant than awk?

> ```
> path_remove ()  { export PATH=`echo -n $PATH | awk -v RS=: -v ORS=: '$0 != "'$1'"' | sed 's/:$//'`;
> ```

Python! It's a more readable and maintainable solution, and it is easy to inspect to see that it's really doing what you want.

Say you want to remove the first path element?

```
PATH="$(echo "$PATH" | python -c "import sys; path = sys.stdin.read().split(':'); del path[0]; print(':'.join(path))")"
```

(Instead of piping from `echo`, `os.getenv['PATH']` would be a little shorter, and provided the same result as the above, but I'm worried that Python might do something with that environment variable, so it's probably best to pipe it directly from the environment you care about.)

Similarly to remove from the end:

```
PATH="$(echo "$PATH" | python -c "import sys; path = sys.stdin.read().split(':'); del path[-1]; print(':'.join(path))")"
```

To make these reusable shell functions that you can, for example, stick in your .bashrc file:

```
strip_path_first () {
    PATH="$(echo "$PATH" | 
    python -c "import sys; path = sys.stdin.read().split(':'); del path[0]; print(':'.join(path))")"
}

strip_path_last () {
    PATH="$(echo "$PATH" | 
    python -c "import sys; path = sys.stdin.read().split(':'); del path[-1]; print(':'.join(path))")"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the three functions shown in @BenBlank's update to his original question. To generalize them, I use a 2-argument form, which allows me to set PATH or any other environment variable I want:

```
path_append ()  { path_remove $1 $2; export $1="${!1}:$2"; }
path_prepend () { path_remove $1 $2; export $1="$2:${!1}"; }
path_remove ()  { export $1="`echo -n ${!1} | awk -v RS=: -v ORS=: '$1 != "'$2'"' | sed 's/:$//'`"; }
```

Examples of use:

```
path_prepend PATH /usr/local/bin
path_append PERL5LIB "$DEVELOPMENT_HOME/p5/src/perlmods"
```

Note that I also added some quotation marks to allow for the proper processing of pathnames that contain spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, putting a colon at the end of PATH, for example, makes removing a path a bit less clumsy & error-prone.

```
path_remove ()  { 
   declare i newPATH
   newPATH="${PATH}:"
   for ((i=1; i<=${#@}; i++ )); do
      #echo ${@:${i}:1}
      newPATH="${newPATH//${@:${i}:1}:/}" 
   done
   export PATH="${newPATH%:}" 
   return 0; 
} 

path_remove_all ()  {
   declare i newPATH
   shopt -s extglob
   newPATH="${PATH}:"
   for ((i=1; i<=${#@}; i++ )); do
      newPATH="${newPATH//+(${@:${i}:1})*([^:]):/}" 
      #newPATH="${newPATH//+(${@:${i}:1})*([^:])+(:)/}" 
   done
   shopt -u extglob 
   export PATH="${newPATH%:}" 
   return 0 
} 

path_remove /opt/local/bin /usr/local/bin

path_remove_all /opt/local /usr/local
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about removing **duplicates** in $PATH, the most elegant way, IMHO, would be not to add them in the first place. In 1 line:

```
if ! $( echo "$PATH" | tr ":" "\n" | grep -qx "$folder" ) ; then PATH=$PATH:$folder ; fi
```

$folder can be be replaced by anything, and may contain spaces ("/home/user/my documents")

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant pure bash solution I've found to date:

```
pathrm () {                                                                      
  local IFS=':'                                                                  
  local newpath                                                                  
  local dir                                                                      
  local pathvar=${2:-PATH}                                                       
  for dir in ${!pathvar} ; do                                                    
    if [ "$dir" != "$1" ] ; then                                                 
      newpath=${newpath:+$newpath:}$dir                                          
    fi                                                                           
  done                                                                           
  export $pathvar="$newpath"                                                        
}

pathprepend () {                                                                 
  pathrm $1 $2                                                                   
  local pathvar=${2:-PATH}                                                       
  export $pathvar="$1${!pathvar:+:${!pathvar}}"                                  
}

pathappend () {                                                                    
  pathrm $1 $2                                                                   
  local pathvar=${2:-PATH}                                                       
  export $pathvar="${!pathvar:+${!pathvar}:}$1"                                  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the other suggested solutions rely only on string matching and don't take into account path segments containing special names like `.`, `..`, or `~`.  The bash function below resolves directory strings in its argument and in path segments to find logical directory matches as well as string matches.

```
rm_from_path() {
  pattern="${1}"
  dir=''
  [ -d "${pattern}" ] && dir="$(cd ${pattern} && pwd)"  # resolve to absolute path

  new_path=''
  IFS0=${IFS}
  IFS=':'
  for segment in ${PATH}; do
    if [[ ${segment} == ${pattern} ]]; then             # string match
      continue
    elif [[ -n ${dir} && -d ${segment} ]]; then
      segment="$(cd ${segment} && pwd)"                 # resolve to absolute path
      if [[ ${segment} == ${dir} ]]; then               # logical directory match
        continue
      fi
    fi
    new_path="${new_path}${IFS}${segment}"
  done
  new_path="${new_path/#${IFS}/}"                       # remove leading colon, if any
  IFS=${IFS0}

  export PATH=${new_path}
}
```

Test:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/foo/bar/baz ~/foo/bar/bif ~/foo/boo/bang
$ PATH0=${PATH}
$ PATH=~/foo/bar/baz/.././../boo/././../bar:${PATH}  # add dir with special names
$ rm_from_path ~/foo/boo/../bar/.  # remove same dir with different special names
$ [ ${PATH} == ${PATH0} ] && echo 'PASS' || echo 'FAIL'
```

Comment: plus one for outside the box

Answer (score 1):

I know this question asks about BASH, which everyone should prefer, but since I enjoy symmetry and sometimes I'm required to use "csh", I built the equivalent to the "path_prepend()", "path_append()" and "path_remove()" elegant solution above.

The gist is that "csh" doesn't have functions, so I put little shell scripts in my personal bin directory that act like the functions.  I create aliases to SOURCE those scripts to make the designated environment variable changes.

~/bin/_path_remove.csh:

```
set _resolve = `eval echo $2`
setenv $1 `eval echo -n \$$1 | awk -v RS=: -v ORS=: '$1 != "'${_resolve}'"' | sed 's/:$//'`;
unset _resolve
```

~/bin/_path_append.csh:

```
source ~/bin/_path_remove.csh $1 $2
set _base = `eval echo \$$1`
set _resolve = `eval echo $2`
setenv $1 ${_base}:${_resolve}
unset _base _resolve
```

~/bin/_path_prepend.csh:

```
source ~/bin/_path_remove.csh $1 $2
set _base = `eval echo \$$1`
set _resolve = `eval echo $2`
setenv $1 ${_resolve}:${_base}
unset _base _resolve
```

~/bin/.cshrc:

```
…
alias path_remove  "source ~/bin/_path_remove.csh  '\!:1' '\!:2'"
alias path_append  "source ~/bin/_path_append.csh  '\!:1' '\!:2'"
alias path_prepend "source ~/bin/_path_prepend.csh '\!:1' '\!:2'"
…
```

You can use them like this...

```
%(csh)> path_append MODULEPATH ${HOME}/modulefiles
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash built-in oneliner (doesn't remove repetition):
`PATH=${PATH/${PATH/#$DIR:*/$DIR:}/}${PATH/${PATH/*:$DIR*/:$DIR}/}`

Answer (score 0):

Since this tends to be quite problematic, as in there IS NO elegant way, I recommend avoiding the problem by rearranging the solution:  build your PATH up rather than attempt to tear it down.

I could be more specific if I knew your real problem context.  In the interim, I will use a software build as the context.

A common problem with software builds is that it breaks on some machines, ultimately due to how someone has configured their default shell (PATH and other environment variables).  The elegant solution is to make your build scripts immune by fully specifying the shell environment.  Code your build scripts to set the PATH and other environment variables based on assembling pieces that you control, such as the location of the compiler, libraries, tools, components, etc.  Make each configurable item something that you can individually set, verify, and then use appropriately in your script.

For example, I have a Maven-based WebLogic-targeted Java build that I inherited at my new employer.  The build script is notorious for being fragile, and another new employee and I spent three weeks (not full time, just here and there, but still many hours) getting it to work on our machines.  An essential step was that I took control of the PATH so that I knew exactly which Java, which Maven, and which WebLogic was being invoked.  I created environment variables to point to each of those tools, then I calculated the PATH based on those plus a few others.  Similar techniques tamed the other configurable settings, until we finally created a reproducible build.

By the way, don't use Maven, Java is okay, and only buy WebLogic if you absolutely need its clustering (but otherwise no, and especially not its proprietary features).

Best wishes.

Comment: sometimes you don't have root access and your admin manages your `PATH`. Sure, you could build you own, but every time your admin moves something you have to figure out where he put it. That sort of defeats the purpose of having an admin.

Answer (score 0):

As with @litb, I contributed an answer to the question "[How do I manipulate $PATH elements in shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273909/how-do-i-manipulate-path-elements-in-shell-scripts)", so my main answer is there.

The 'split' functionality in `bash` and other Bourne shell derivatives is most neatly achieved with `$IFS`, the inter-field separator.  For example, to set the positional arguments (`$1`, `$2`, ...) to the elements of PATH, use:

```
set -- $(IFS=":"; echo "$PATH")
```

It will work OK as long as there are no spaces in $PATH.  Making it work for path elements containing spaces is a non-trivial exercise - left for the interested reader.  It is probably simpler to deal with it using a scripting language such as Perl.

I also have a script, `clnpath`, which I use extensively for setting my PATH.  I documented it in the answer to "[How to keep from duplicating PATH variable in csh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135754/how-to-keep-from-duplicating-path-variable-in-csh#137981)".

Comment: IFS=: a=( $PATH ); IFS= splitting is also nice. works if they contain spaces too. but then you got an array, and have to fiddle with for loops and such to remove the names.

Comment: Yes; it gets fiddly - as with my updated comment, it is probably simpler to use a scripting language at this point.

Answer (score 0):

What makes this problem annoying are the fencepost cases among first and last elements.  The problem can be elegantly solved by changing IFS and using an array, but I don't know how to re-introduce the colon once the path is converted to array form.

Here is a slightly less elegant version that removes one directory from `$PATH` using string manipulation only.  I have tested it.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#   remove_from_path dirname
#
#   removes $1 from user's $PATH

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 pathname" 1>&2; exit 1;
fi

delendum="$1"
NEWPATH=
xxx="$IFS"
IFS=":"
for i in $PATH ; do
  IFS="$xxx"
  case "$i" in
    "$delendum") ;; # do nothing
    *) [ -z "$NEWPATH" ] && NEWPATH="$i" || NEWPATH="$NEWPATH:$i" ;;
  esac
done

PATH="$NEWPATH"
echo "$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Perl one-liner:

```
PATH=`perl -e '$a=shift;$_=$ENV{PATH};s#:$a(:)|^$a:|:$a$#$1#;print' /home/usr/bin`
```

The `$a` variable gets the path to be removed.  The `s` (substitute) and `print` commands implicitly operate on the `$_` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Good stuff here.
I use this one to keep from adding dupes in the first place.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
######################################################################################
#
# Allows a list of additions to PATH with no dupes
# 
# Patch code below into your $HOME/.bashrc file or where it
# will be seen at login.
#
# Can also be made executable and run as-is.
#
######################################################################################

# add2path=($HOME/bin .)                  ## uncomment space separated list 
if [ $add2path ]; then                    ## skip if list empty or commented out
for nodup in ${add2path[*]}
do
    case $PATH in                 ## case block thanks to MIKE511
    $nodup:* | *:$nodup:* | *:$nodup ) ;;    ## if found, do nothing
    *) PATH=$PATH:$nodup          ## else, add it to end of PATH or
    esac                          ## *) PATH=$nodup:$PATH   prepend to front
done
export PATH
fi
## debug add2path
echo
echo " PATH == $PATH"
echo
```

Comment: You can simplify your case statement by adding a leading and trailing colon to the PATH string: `case ":$PATH:" in (*:"$nodup":*) ;; (*) PATH="$PATH:$nodup" ;; esac`

Answer (score 0):

With extended globbing enabled it's possible to do the following:

```
# delete all /opt/local paths in PATH
shopt -s extglob 
printf "%s\n" "${PATH}" | tr ':' '\n' | nl
printf "%s\n" "${PATH//+(\/opt\/local\/)+([^:])?(:)/}" | tr ':' '\n' | nl 

man bash | less -p extglob
```

Answer (score 0):

Extended globbing one-liner (well, sort of):

```
path_remove ()  { shopt -s extglob; PATH="${PATH//+(${1})+([^:])?(:)/}"; export PATH="${PATH%:}"; shopt -u extglob; return 0; }
```

There seems no need to escape slashes in $1.

```
path_remove ()  { shopt -s extglob; declare escArg="${1//\//\\/}"; PATH="${PATH//+(${escArg})+([^:])?(:)/}"; export PATH="${PATH%:}"; shopt -u extglob; return 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding colons to PATH we could also do something like:

```
path_remove ()  { 
   declare i newPATH
   # put a colon at the beginning & end AND double each colon in-between
   newPATH=":${PATH//:/::}:"   
   for ((i=1; i<=${#@}; i++)); do
       #echo ${@:${i}:1}
       newPATH="${newPATH//:${@:${i}:1}:/}"   # s/:\/fullpath://g
   done
   newPATH="${newPATH//::/:}"
   newPATH="${newPATH#:}"      # remove leading colon
   newPATH="${newPATH%:}"      # remove trailing colon
   unset PATH 
   PATH="${newPATH}" 
   export PATH
   return 0 
} 


path_remove_all ()  {
   declare i newPATH extglobVar
   extglobVar=0
   # enable extended globbing if necessary
   [[ ! $(shopt -q extglob) ]]  && { shopt -s extglob; extglobVar=1; }
   newPATH=":${PATH}:"
   for ((i=1; i<=${#@}; i++ )); do
      newPATH="${newPATH//:+(${@:${i}:1})*([^:])/}"     # s/:\/path[^:]*//g
   done
   newPATH="${newPATH#:}"      # remove leading colon
   newPATH="${newPATH%:}"      # remove trailing colon
   # disable extended globbing if it was enabled in this function
   [[ $extglobVar -eq 1 ]] && shopt -u extglob
   unset PATH 
   PATH="${newPATH}" 
   export PATH
   return 0 
} 

path_remove /opt/local/bin /usr/local/bin

path_remove_all /opt/local /usr/local
```

Answer (score 0):

In path_remove_all (by proxxy):

```
-newPATH="${newPATH//:+(${@:${i}:1})*([^:])/}" 
+newPATH="${newPATH//:${@:${i}:1}*([^:])/}"        # s/:\/path[^:]*//g
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is a very old thread, I thought this solution might be of interest:

```
PATH="/usr/lib/ccache:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
REMOVE="ccache" # whole or part of a path :)
export PATH=$(IFS=':';p=($PATH);unset IFS;p=(${p[@]%%$REMOVE});IFS=':';echo "${p[*]}";unset IFS)
echo $PATH # outputs /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

found it on this [blog post](http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2009/05/remove-path-from-path-variable-in-bash.html).  I think I like this one most :)

Answer (score 0):

I took a slightly different approach than most people here and focussed specifically on just string manipulation, like so:

```
path_remove () {
    if [[ ":$PATH:" == *":$1:"* ]]; then
        local dirs=":$PATH:"
        dirs=${dirs/:$1:/:}
        export PATH="$(__path_clean $dirs)"
    fi
}
__path_clean () {
    local dirs=${1%?}
    echo ${dirs#?}
}
```

The above is a simplified example of the final functions I use. I've also created `path_add_before` and `path_add_after` allowing you insert a path before/after a specified path already in PATH.

The full set of functions are available in [path_helpers.sh](https://github.com/jimeh/dotfiles/blob/master/shell/helpers/path_helpers.sh) in my [dotfiles](https://github.com/jimeh/dotfiles). They fully support removing/appending/prepending/inserting at beginning/middle/end of the PATH string.

Answer (score 0):

The trailing ':' is caused by the fact that you are setting the line ending, not the separator. I use resource limitted units and like to pack everything into a single script, without these oddities:

```
path_remove () {
    PATH="$(echo -n $PATH | awk -v RS=: -v ORS= '$0 != "'$1'"{print s _ $0;s=":"}')"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly elegant, but it does use the external sed.
Furthermore it removes all paths containing the search string $1. Neither does it leave a dangling : at the end in the event of the removed path being the last on the PATH.

```
PATH=`echo $PATH | sed 's/:[^:]*$1[^:]*//g'`
```

This alternative does leave a dangling final : however.

```
PATH=`echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | grep -v $1 | tr "\n" ":"`
```

The alternatives without backticks are:

```
PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed 's/:[^:]*$1[^:]*//g')

PATH=$(echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | grep -v $1 | tr "\n" ":")
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Ben Blank's Update, the following is simpler and supports paths with single or multiple spaces in them:

```
path_remove ()  { local P=":$PATH:"; P="${P/:$1:/:}"; export PATH="${P:1:-1}"; }
path_append ()  { path_remove "$1"; export PATH="$PATH:$1"; }
path_prepend () { path_remove "$1"; export PATH="$1:$PATH"; }
```

Use / test like this:

```
path_append john; echo "$PATH"
path_append "my dir"; echo "$PATH"
path_append "special   dir"; echo "$PATH"

path_append john; echo "$PATH" # john moves to the end of the path

path_remove "my dir"; echo "$PATH" 
path_remove "special   dir"; echo "$PATH" 
path_remove "john"; echo "$PATH"
```

**Update**:

Being there, also prepared the following:

```
# easily manipulate _any_ list of the form a:b:c
list_remove  () { local L=":${!1}:"; L="${L/:$2:/:}"; IFS= read -a "$1" <<<"${L:1:-1}"; }
list_append  () { list_remove "$@"; IFS= read -a "$1" <<<"${!1}${!1:+:}$2"; }
list_prepend () { list_remove "$@"; IFS= read -a "$1" <<<"$2${!1:+:}${!1}"; }
```

So you can do things like:

```
list_prepend MANPATH ~/man; export MANPATH
list_prepend PERL5LIB ~/perl5/lib/perl5; export PERL5LIB
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's "remove" references to /path/to/something from the PATH:

Bash:

```
PATH=${PATH/something/nope/}
```

Bonus answer for Windows Batch:

```
set PATH=%PATH:something=nope%
```

Anyone has a simpler solution? :)

Comment: this adds something to the path. the question is about removing somehting from the path