# CMake variable to use in ExternalProject_Add BUILD_COMMAND which compiles to .o as current settings would

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to compile a single `.cpp` file in an otherwise header-only project as the `BUILD_COMMAND` of my `ExternalProject_Add`.  Ideally, I'd like this build command to compile this one cpp file exactly as it's compiling everything else in the project, with all the associated flags, debugging info and so forth.

I can't seem to find how to make a build command which does this.  Any ideas?

Comment: *ExternalProject* doesn't inherit compile options from the main project, you need to pass these options to the external project through appropriate CMake variables. If you want to compile `.cpp` file with main project's options, just compile it with `add_executable` command. You may make target created by this command dependent from the `ExternalProject` one. So `.cpp` will be garanteed existed when you compile it.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021448/how-can-cmake-arguments-be-forwarded-to-externalproject