# Passing variables and their values from one ExternalProject dependency to another using cmake (in the context of zlib and libpng)

Tags: cmake, dependency-management, zlib, libpng

I am still at the beginning of my journey regarding `ExternalProject`. I have two projects used by my main project as dependencies: **libpng** and **zlib**. The former depends on the latter.

Inside the official [`CMakeLists.txt` of **libpng**](https://github.com/glennrp/libpng/blob/libpng16/CMakeLists.txt) I see that there is the option `PNG_BUILD_ZLIB`, which you have to disable if you want to use a custom version of `zlib`. Currently my two externals look like this:

```
ExternalProject_Add(zlib
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/deps/zlib
    
    INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
    DOWNLOAD_DIR ""
    TMP_DIR ${DEPS_TMP}/zlib
    STAMP_DIR ${DEPS_STAMP}/zlib
    LOG_DIR ${DEPS_LOG}/zlib
    BINARY_DIR ${DEPS_BUILD}/zlib
    SOURCE_DIR ${DEPS}/zlib

    INSTALL_COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E echo "Skipping install step for dependency zlib"
    INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}

    BUILD_ALWAYS OFF
)

# Set zlib variables required by libpng
ExternalProject_Get_property(zlib BINARY_DIR)
ExternalProject_Get_property(zlib SOURCE_DIR)
set(zlib_DIR "${BINARY_DIR}/Debug" CACHE PATH "zlib dir" FORCE)
set(ZLIB_ROOT ${SOURCE_DIR} CACHE PATH "zlib root" FORCE) # ${zlib_DIR}
set(ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS ${SOURCE_DIR} CACHE PATH "zlib include dir" FORCE)

if(WIN32)
    set(ZLIB_LIBRARY ${zlib_DIR}/zlibd.dll CACHE FILEPATH "zlib dynamic library" FORCE)
    set(ZLIB_LIBRARIES ${zlib_DIR}/zlibd.dll CACHE FILEPATH "zlib dynamic library" FORCE)
else()
    set(ZLIB_LIBRARY ${zlib_DIR}/libzlibd.so CACHE FILEPATH "zlib dynamic library" FORCE)
    set(ZLIB_LIBRARIES ${zlib_DIR}/libzlibd.so CACHE FILEPATH "zlib dynamic library" FORCE)
endif()

ExternalProject_Add(libpng 
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/deps/png

    DEPENDS zlib

    INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
    DOWNLOAD_DIR ""
    TMP_DIR ${DEPS_TMP}/png
    STAMP_DIR ${DEPS_STAMP}/png
    LOG_DIR ${DEPS_LOG}/png
    BINARY_DIR ${DEPS_BUILD}/png
    SOURCE_DIR ${DEPS}/libpng

    INSTALL_COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E echo "Skipping install step for dependency libpng"
    INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}

    BUILD_ALWAYS OFF

    CMAKE_ARGS
        "-DPNG_BUILD_ZLIB=1"       # Use zlib built as a dependency of this project
        "-DPNG_SHARED=1"
        "-DPNG_STATIC=0"
        "-DPNG_TESTS=0"
        "-DPNG_EXECUTABLES=0"
        "-DPNG_HARDWARE_OPTIMIZATIONS=1"
        "-DPNG_DEBUG=0"
)
```

where

- `${DEPS}` points at a directory where currently every dependency's source code resides and is manually downloaded using `git submodules` commands
- `${DEPS_xyz}` points at a `ExternalProject` directory for a specific purpose (logs, stamps, build files, temporary files etc.) and all are placed inside the build directory of the whole project.

The problem I am having is that I am failing at passing the include directory to **libpng** and this results in the header `zlib.h` not being found during the build step for that dependency. Apparently

```
set(ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS ${SOURCE_DIR} CACHE PATH "zlib include dir" FORCE)
```

isn't really passed to the dependency (but in itself it is pointing at the correct path on the filesystem where the header file is included).

Do I have to add the include directory as a `CMAKE_ARGS` entry or is there some other easier way?

I also checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25535987/1559401) but the suggested solution (I just passed the stuff directly into my `CMAKE_ARGS`)

```
CMAKE_ARGS
    "-DPNG_BUILD_ZLIB=1" # Use zlib built as a dependency of this project
    "-DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS=\"${${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}}\"" # Pass the ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS to the dependency using the value of the variable set above
    "-DPNG_SHARED=1"
    "-DPNG_STATIC=0"
    "-DPNG_TESTS=0"
    "-DPNG_EXECUTABLES=0"
    "-DPNG_HARDWARE_OPTIMIZATIONS=1"
    "-DPNG_DEBUG=0"
```

doesn't work.

Comment: "Do I have to add the include directory as a CMAKE_ARGS entry or is there some other easier way?" - Yes, you need to pass `ZLIB_INCLIDE_DIRS` and `ZLIB_LIBRARIES` variables as a CMAKE_ARGS entries. Since you have already compute their values in your `CMakeLists.txt`, passing is straghtforward: `"-DZLIB_INCLIDE_DIRS=${ZLIB_INCLIDE_DIRS}" "-DZLIB_LIBRARIES=${ZLIB_LIBRARIES}"`. Not sure what do you want to achive by extra escaping `\"${${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}}\""`.

Comment: The problem is that these variables are filled during the configuration and not build step. So I am struggling to find a way to populate `ZLIB_LIBRARIES` with the actual `lib` file path. I have two options: 1)GLOB it thus allowing me to set it regardless of prefixes and suffixes (e.g. debug build on Win produces `zlibd.lib` but a release one on Win produces `zlib1.lib`) with a good regex or 2)write fixed names. 1) is a no go since I cannot glob files that are not there (hence requirement to run cmake and build multiple times. 2) is difficult since some libs contain version numbers.

Comment: @Tsyvarev `\"${${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}}\"` is a leftover from a previous experiment.