# how to remove particular path in cygwin

Tags: path, cygwin

I want to ask how to remove path in cygwin. Let's say I have 3 paths:

```
PATH=path1:path2:path3
```

I want to remove path2 so it will be:

```
PATH=path1:path3
```

But actually i have a lot of path inside and it will painful to rewrite it manually. Any suggestion?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370047/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-remove-a-path-from-the-path-variable-in-bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to use the `bash` or `csh` command-line:

```
   export PATH=`echo $PATH | sed s/:path2//`
```

But this will only work 99.9% of the time. To handle the edge cases, such as when `path2` is at the start, or when it is part of another path, you'll need:

```
   export PATH=`echo $PATH | sed "s/:path2:/:/g;s/^path2://;s/:path2$//"`
```

Comment: i got this when echo $PATH, "echo $PATH | sed/:PHP/xampp/" :D

Comment: @kreamik: I am sorry, but I do not understand. Perhaps by `sed/:PHP...` you mean `sed s/:PHP...`?

Comment: What shell are you using? (I think cygwin defaults to `tcsh`, but I might be misremembering.)

Comment: i type "which bash" i got "/usr/bin/bash"

Comment: i have PATH : /cygdrive/c/oracle/;/cygdrive/c/python;/cygdrive/c/PHP/;/cygdrive/c/java/, i want to chage /cygdrive/c/PHP/ to /cygdrive/c/xampp/, how to do that?

Comment: sorry, i used single quote instead of backtick :D, you're great .. thx alot