# How to remove directories from PATH when deactivating a conda environment

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, anaconda, conda

I have created an conda environment and in that environment I have installed a tool  called minibarcoder, which was developed by somebody else than me. https://github.com/asrivathsan/miniBarcoder

The tool is mostly a set of scripts (python or shell). To make it easy to use I moved all the scripts of the tool to the bin folder of the conda enviroment.

However, the miniBarcoder scripts in the bin folder depend on set of other scripts located in the folder `scripts`. I moved that folder as well to the bin folder.

The folder `scripts` contains some scripts, that I want to add to my `$PATH` variable when using the environment and when I close the environment I want to remove those scripts from the PATH variable when I deactivate the environment.

As instructed by the conda manual 
(https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#macos-and-linux)
, I can add the scripts folder to my PATH using an environment file that is located in the folder:

> /work/projects/nn9305k/src/anaconda/envs/minibarcoder/etc/conda/activate.d

the file `env_vars.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/sh

#add scripts folder to PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/work/projects/nn9305k/src/anaconda/envs/minibarcoder/bin/scripts
```

When activating the environment it is the folder is added to the PATH variable.

Now my problem is how to remove this folder from the PATH variable when I deactivate the environment.

For that I create a file `env_vars.sh` in the folder:

> /work/projects/nn9305k/src/anaconda/envs/minibarcoder/etc/conda/deactivate.d

I have tried the following:

```
    #!/bin/sh

#remove scripts from PATH
export PATH=$(echo ${PATH%:/work/projects/nn9305k/src/anaconda/envs/minibarcoder/bin/scripts
```

This does not remove the directory from the PATH variable, but when I run that command on the commandline, I do remove it from the PATH variable. Why is it not working in my env_vars.sh file.?

Any hints are welcome

Comment: I'd look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370047/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-remove-a-path-from-the-path-variable-in-bash

Comment: Thanks, I had found that earlier but not tried it. Will do that.