# MacOS stil points to python3.6

Tags: python, macos

I can confirm I installed python3.8

```
brew install python
Warning: python@3.8 3.8.5 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 3.8.5, run `brew reinstall python@3.8
```

However, macOS still points to python3.6

```
$python --version
Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda, Inc.

$ python
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 29 2018, 19:04:46)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

What's the workaround to point to version 3.8?

Comment: Where, if at all, is `/usr/local/bin` in your `PATH`?

Comment: `$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/anaconda3/bin:/Users/Sani/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Either you need to run `rehash` to tell the shell to look again for a version of `python` in `/usr/local/bin`, or you need to use `python3` to access the newly installed Python 3.

Comment: It finds Python3.6 in the `/anaconda3/bin` directory before it finds python in the directory in which Homebrew installed Python3.8.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty certain the simple fix here since your path is small is to get rid of the

`/anaconda3/bin` and `/Users/Sani/anaconda3/bin` in your PATH variable.

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13135333/13636400):

`export PATH=$(p=$(echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | grep -v "/anaconda3/bin" | tr "\n" ":"); echo ${p%:})`
We are taking whatever is inside the grep command and removing it

`export PATH=$(p=$(echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | grep -v "/Users/sani/anaconda3/bin" | tr "\n" ":"); echo ${p%:})`

You may need to restart your terminal to see if it changed. I assume the Python3.6 is being picked up through the Anaconda bins.

Otherwise yes uninstalling Anaconda3 will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way out

```
conda install python=3.8
```

works for me.

```
$ python
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 11:26:31) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```