# How to keep from duplicating path variable in ksh

Tags: path, ksh

Similar question to [How to keep from duplicating path variable in csh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135754/how-to-keep-from-duplicating-path-variable-in-csh).
But I don't use csh.

```
PATH=${SOMETHING}:${PATH}
```

How do I remove duplicates from PATH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this oneliner, but it depends on gawk.

```
PATH=$(echo $PATH|tr ":" "\n"|gawk '!($0 in a) { a[$0];print}'|paste -sd: - )
```

Comment: fwiw, the above works fine on OpenBSD with good old 'awk' instead of 'gawk'