# How to keep from duplicating path variable in Windows

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables

Similar question to [How to keep from duplicating path variable in csh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135754/how-to-keep-from-duplicating-path-variable-in-csh) and [How to keep from duplicating path variable in ksh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586741/how-to-keep-from-duplicating-path-variable-in-ksh). But this time using Windows command line (`cmd.exe`).

```
PATH=C:\path\to\bin;%PATH%
```

How do I remove duplicates from `PATH`? It would like to do this in an automated way: as part of our build process a specific path is added to the environment variable `PATH`; when done 20+ times that path is present 20+ times. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Copy all the values of the Environment variable in a Textpad or Notepad++ and sort it. Then remove the duplicates. After that replace the existing Environment Variable values with the non redundant values.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to do this automatically, i.e. in a makefile, or as part of a batch file.

Comment: Similar question on SU: https://superuser.com/questions/1223976/how-do-i-keep-each-path-entry-only-once/1541042#1541042 (How to remove PATH duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/586748/911550:

```
echo %PATH% | tr ; \n | awk "!($0 in a) { a[$0]; print }" | paste -sd; - > TEMPORARY.FILE
set /P PATH=< TEMPORARY.FILE
del TEMPORARY.FILE
```

`tr`, `awk` and `paste` can be downloaded from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net. (Actually, the first I do on any new Windows workstation is using the [Automated gnuwin32 download tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/getgnuwin32/))