# TCSH, what does this line do? Trying to port to BASH

Tags: bash, csh, tcsh

I'm trying to update some scripts from tcsh to bash to reflect the bash preference of some users.  Needless to say, I don't know csh.  Can someone tell me what this line does?

```
alias prepend 'if (-d \!:2) if ("$\!:1" \!~ *"\!:2"*) export \!:1 "\!:2":${\!:1}'
```

Comment: Apparently there's an `export` command (could be an alias) visible from tcsh/csh. That name conflicts with bash's built-in `export` command. You'll have to resolve that somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That *probably* prepends a directory onto a variable if said directory doesn't already exist in said variable.

Here's what it says, in English: if the second argument is a directory, then if the first argument interpreted as a variable does not contain the text of the second argument, then "export" the string "second argument colon contents of first argument" into the first argument.

It all depends upon what `export` does.  In my experience, `export` is an alias for `setenv`, but that is not guaranteed.

I would suggest a test to see if this does what I think.  First, echo your path.  Then run `prepend PATH /a/new/directory/that/exists`.  Then echo your path again.  If you see that "/a/new/directory/that/exists" is now in your path variable, then you can be reasonably sure export is an alias for setenv.

Finally, [this SO post lists strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135754/how-to-keep-from-duplicating-path-variable-in-csh) to implement a similar thing in other languages and shells.

Comment: It depends on what `export` does; there's no such built-in command in csh/tcsh.

Comment: @KeithThompson: True. In the bastard `tcsh` environments I've been tortured with, `export` was an alias to `setenv`. Nonetheless, I've weakened my answer a bit.

Comment: I suggest that rather than just adding the word *probably*, you should explicitly acknowledge that it depends on what `export` does. Future readers may not read these comments.