# why is my $PATH much longer than .bash_profile

Tags: macos, bash

echo $PATH shows:

```
/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin://anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/stefankaros/bin/FDK/Tools/osx
```

my ~/.bash_profile is:

```
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# added by Anaconda 2.0.1 installer
export PATH="//anaconda/bin:$PATH"

# Initialization for FDK command line tools.Tue Oct  7 20:01:15 2014
FDK_EXE="/Users/stefankaros/bin/FDK/Tools/osx"
PATH=${PATH}:"/Users/stefankaros/bin/FDK/Tools/osx"
export PATH
export FDK_EXE

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-10-22_at_21:44:05: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

I do not have .bashrc or any other file that starts with .bash in my home dir.
in my PATH,where does the opt/x11/bin come from? why is use/bin duplicated?
In my .bash_profile, what does export FDK_exe do? PATH was just exported in the line before?

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask where the initial value of `$PATH` comes from.

Comment: It's probably coming from `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc`. Or it may be inherited from `init`.

Comment: Given that the system is Mac OS X, maybe [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) is an appropriate place to ask.

Comment: Funny or depressing?  How all of these guys think they have to `export PATH` even though it's basically guaranteed to be exported already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac OS X, there is a file `/etc/paths` which contains (on my Yosemite machine):

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

These are the elements on your PATH that you don't set explicitly in your `.bash_profile`.  There's also a directory `/etc/paths.d` but that's empty on my machine.  See also `man path_helper` and `/usr/libexec/path_helper`, called from `/etc/profile`.

You could clean up your PATH to remove duplicate elements.  See [How to keep from duplicating PATH variable in `csh`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135754/how-to-keep-from-duplicating-path-variable-in-csh) — which has relevant answers even if you use Bourne shell derivatives.

Comment: yep! that's where it came from. thanks. i guess i can edit my .bash_profile in confidence now!

Comment: OK; what you showed certainly matched `/etc/profile` on my machine — but it could have been copied to `/etc/bashrc` (though it would not be a good idea to have done so).  I could add the files to my answer, but I don't think they add all that much value.